# Is there a way to change/redirect "indirect" self-references?

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js, merge, self-reference

I'm developing a website using Knockout.js, but my question is way more general, so don't focus on that.

I reference the object within itself by its variable name, in this case `viewModel`, like so:

```
var viewModel = {
    propA: "propA",
    fnA: function () {
        alert("I am " + viewModel.propA); //the same as this.propA
    }
};
```

That way, I don't run into any trouble when it comes to sub-objects and other "fancy" stuff.

Now, I need to merge another object into my viewModel, but I run into a reference problem:

```
g_test = {}; //The way with this global variable is just for demonstration purposes

(function () {
    var viewModel = {
        propA: "propA",
        fnA: function () {
            alert("I am " + viewModel.propB);
        }
    };
    g_test.vmA = viewModel;
})();

(function () {
    var viewModel = {
        propB: "propB",
        fnB: function () {
            alert("I am " + viewModel.propA);
        }
    }

    /** merge viewModel "A" into viewModel "B" */
    var vmA = g_test.vmA;
    for (var key in vmA) {
        if (vmA.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            viewModel[key] = vmA[key];
        }
    }

    viewModel.fnA(); //I am undefined
    viewModel.fnB(); //I am propA
})();
```

As you can see, `fnB` knows `propA`, but `fnA` does not know `propB`.

Using `this` as reference to the `viewModel` object however does the job. But I don't want to run through my whole object and replace every `viewModel` with `this` or introduce respective "helper variables" where needed, because this would take me ages. Plus, to my eyes it would mean that it's impossible to merge two objects which don't have bidirectional knowledge of each other.

Is there a senseful way of letting the `viewModel` variable in `fnA` point to viewModel "B" without having to know viewModel "B"?

Comment: JavaScript has lexical scope. The only way to change `viewModel` in `fnA` would be to assign a new value to it. But that is not possible in your example, since `viewModel` is local to the IIFE.

Comment: replace `viewModel.propB` with `this.propB` and it works

Comment: Using `this` is the answer. That what it's there for.

Comment: Also note that with your approach, the `fnB` function prints the `propA` that's copied over rather than the original (thus they could have different values).

Comment: @MichaelBest I know, I want the very copy. But is JAG's and your suggestion really the "minimally invasive" solution? It's certainly not impossible, but a hell lot of effort which I'd really like to avoid if somehow possible. Not only for effort reasons, but also for reasons of having some possibility of adding parts to this object/viewModel in a modular way.

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple viewModels and then trying to merge them seems like a problematic approach, and I don't know what you're trying to achieve with it. There is probably a better way (at the very least, using `this` would have been the right choice for creating [mixins](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/)). But assuming that either there's a good reason or it's too much effort to rework it now, let's look at your issue.

You have two viewModels, and you want to merge them in such a way that each knows about the members of the other. You merge them in one direction, so B knows about A, but A doesn't know about B. You need to merge the other direction, as well. `Object.assign` is a convenient way to do what your loop does, but if you are on a pre-`Object.assign` browser, you can add another loop that goes through `viewModel` and copies properties from it into `vmA`.

The result is that you have two viewModels whose methods refer to each other. Each has `propA`, `propB`, `fnA`, and `fnB`, but `fnA` (in both objects) refers to the member of object `A` and vice-versa.

```js
g_test = {}; //The way with this global variable is just for demonstration purposes

function mergeObjects(obj1, obj2) {
  Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
  Object.assign(obj2, obj1);
}

(function() {
  var viewModel = {
    propA: "propA",
    fnA: function() {
      alert("fnA: I am " + viewModel.propB);
    }
  };
  g_test.vmA = viewModel;
})();

(function() {
  var viewModel = {
    propB: "propB",
    fnB: function() {
      alert("fnB: I am " + viewModel.propA);
    }
  }

  mergeObjects(g_test.vmA, viewModel);

  // to demonstrate which value is outputted by which function
  g_test.vmA.propA = "A.propA";   // not used
  g_test.vmA.propB = "A.propB";   // used by fnA
  viewModel.propA = "B.propA";    // used by fnB
  viewModel.propB = "B.propB";    // not used

  viewModel.fnA(); //I am A.propB
  viewModel.fnB(); //I am B.propA
  // also
  g_test.vmA.fnA();
  g_test.vmA.fnB();
})();
```